# Как проверить валидность скрипта для cron?

Tags: linux, docker, cron

Потребовалось автоматизировать запуск кое-каких задач для чего я выбрал `cron`, так как нужен их периодический запуск. Но возникла очень уже бесящая ситуация: запускаю `cron`, а ничего не происходит - оказывается, что в скрипте опечатка или типа того, а `cron` работает буд-то ни в чем не бывало! Как вообще понять в чем проблема и есть ли она вообще, когда `cron` никак о них не сообщает?

Comment: В системных логах должны быть ошибки, не?

Comment: @andreymal не знаю - я работаю в докере, системные логи отключены

Comment: @TotalPusher при чем сдесь вообще `nginx`? Вопрос про `cron` и проверку файла запуска. Что же касается системных логов, то это конечно хорошо, вот только вывод логов уже занят тулой, которая запускается cron-ом, так что это не вариант. Неужели у cron отсутствует банальная проверка запускаемого скрипта? Чтобы он валился или хотя бы выдал сообщение в поток вывода ошибок?

Comment: @TotalPusher вы понимаете что не будет работать если скрипт cron-а не валидный?

Comment: @TotalPusher я не понимаю, вы вопрос читали? Про логи я вообще ничего не писал для начала. Про bash скрипты тоже ничего. Откуда вы все это понабирали? У меня проблема в скрипте для `crona`, который ложится в `/etc/cron.d`. И если он не валидный, то никакое перенаправление вывода не поможет - потому что `cron` не запустит эту задачу

Comment: @TotalPusher 1) содержание не имеет значение, так как вопрос о том, как обработать скрипт с неверным содержанием (например опечаткой); 2) какое это имеет значение? 3) при запуске cron в stderr (желательно еще чтобы и завершился с ненулевым кодом) (запуск типа `cron -f`

Comment: @TotalPusher блин, да куда вас опять понесло? Какой яп? О чем вы? Еще раз: ошибка (опечатка) прямо в файле для `cron`, который ложится в `/etc/cron.d`. А вообще я предлагаю закончить данную дискусию: либо я как-то не так изъясняюсь, либо вы игнорируете написанное мной. Что из двух - я не хочу разбираться

Comment: 1. вывод ошибок, возникших при выполнении задания, crond отсылает на почту пользователю, которому принадлежит задание. 2. запускать несколько экземпляров crond — очень плохая идея.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch по изложенному вами в вопросе действительно трудно что-то понять, хотя бы потому, что у крона не скрипты, а конфиги (или кронтабы, ещё однозначнее). Естественно, при ссылке на "скрипты" возникают вопросы, отношения к крону не имеющие. Об ошибках в парсинге конфигов крон сообщает в логи. Ели вы отказались от ведения/чтения логов, то это вы зря-я...

Comment: Поизучай опции. Можно делать `crontab -T ...` или `crond -x test` или не знаю, что там  у тебя используется. Только он найдёт совсем уже лажу. Многие выражения валидны, но не выполняют то, что ты хотел изначально.